# Share an Excel file online with an autoopen add-in

Tags: ms-office, microsoft-graph-api, office-js, office-addins, excel-online

I have an Excel file in my OneDrive. When editing the file, I often use an add-in from Microsoft AppSource that I submitted.

Now, I want to share this Excel file by a URL link, such that other users click on the link, open the file on Excel Online and **see directly the opened add-in**.

I have all the control of this add-in, and this Excel file.

Does anyone know how to set up the add-in and the Excel file to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can set that up with an element in the manifest and an API. Or by working at the OOXML level. For details, see [Automatically Open a Task Pane with a document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document).

Comment: Could you confirm if it is possible to enable autoopen of a task pane in a document in OneDrive (i.e. when users view this document in Excel Online, the task pane will be automatically opened)?

Comment: Yes. The configuration is saved with the document, so it does not matter where the document is stored.